# Google Docs: Catching keyup events

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to implement a custom autocomplete for google docs.

Therefore I would need to access any kind of text-input events within the document.

Are there any ideas how this could be done with App Scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs doesn't have the `onEdit()` or `onChange()` event available to it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers

I doubt that what you want is possible.

Inside of HTML, you can watch for a key event.  But that would only be inside of a Dialog Box created with HTML, or a Sidebar with HTML.